# Markov chain counterexample

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have to show that the equation

$P(X_u=b|X_t \in A, X_s=a)= P(X_u=b|X_t\in A)$

is wrong for a time-homogeneous Markov chain $(X_k)_{k\in \mathbb N_0}$ on a finit space $E$ with $s<t<u \in \mathbb N_0$, $a,b \in E$ and for all $A \subset E$.
Furthermore there is a hint with the following graph:

[image]

which shows a markov chain with its stochastic matrix

$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1& 0 & 0 &  0\\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$  .

I somehow can't find a counterexample and don't really know how i can calculate $P(X_u=b|X_t \in A, X_s=a)$. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Try $b=5$, $A=\{4,5\}$, $a=3$, $u=3$, $t=2$, for the initial distribution $P(X_0=1)=1$.

Comment: So that $P(X_3=5|X_2 \in \{4,5\}, X_1=3)=P(X_3=5|X_2 =5, X_1=3)=1$ but what is $P(X_3=5|X_2 \in \{4,5\})$

Comment: Sorry but can't you compute $P(X_2\in\{4,5\}\mid X_0=1)$ and $P(X_2\in\{4,5\},X_3=5\mid X_0=1)$?

Comment: No, the exercise clearly says, that I need a counterexample with a markov chain of this graph to show that $P(X_u=b|X_t \in A, X_s=a)= P(X_u=b|X_t\in A)$ is wrong with $s<t<u \in \mathbb N_0$, $a,b \in E$ and $\forall A \subset E$. I also think, that $u-t$ or $t-s$ could be higher than $1$, because the exercise says it's a time-homogeneous markov chain. But I somehow really don't see parameters, which work.

Comment: Which one are you unable to compute?

Comment: You said I should try $b=5$, $A=\{4,5\}$, $a=3$, $u=3$, $t=2$ and I think $s=0$. That would lead to $P(X_3=5|X_2 \in \{4,5\}, X_0=3)$ and $P(X_3=5|X_2 \in \{4,5\})$ in the equation. Then you said $P(X_2\in\{4,5\}\mid X_0=1)$ and $P(X_2\in\{4,5\},X_3=5\mid X_0=1)$ could work, which means you set $s=0$, $t=2$, $u=3$, $A=\{4,5\}$, $a=1$ and $b=5$, so we have the equation $P(X_t \in A \mid X_s=a)=P(X_t \in A, X_u=b \mid X_s=a)$. But that isn't the equation of this exercise. I don't get what you mean. Please explain.

Comment: $s=1$ (as your first comment itself indicates...).

Comment: Ok, so I was right with $P(X_3=5|X_2 \in \{4,5\}, X_1=3)=P(X_3=5|X_2 =5, X_1=3)=1$? But how do I calculate $P(X_3=5|X_2 \in \{4,5\})$? Because the markov chain can go to $X_3=5$, if $X_2=5$, but it can't go there, if $X_2=4$ is true. Why does $P(X_2\in\{4,5\}\mid X_0=1)$ and $P(X_2\in\{4,5\},X_3=5\mid X_0=1)$ help me in this situation? I think $P(X_2\in\{4,5\}\mid X_0=1)=1$ because of $\text{matrix}^2$.

Comment: Yes this is the whole idea of the example I suggested -- and I believe you now just have to *compute*.

Comment: So I can say case no. 1 of $P(X_3=5|X_2 \in \{4,5\})$ is $P(X_3=5|X_2 =5)=1$ and case no. 2 is $P(X_3=5|X_2 = 4)=0 \neq 1$, which already shows that this equation isn't always true.

Comment: I'm sorry now I get what you meant. $P(X_3=5|X_2 \in \{4,5\})=\frac{P(X_3=5,X_2 \in \{4,5\})}{P(X_2 \in \{4,5\})}$. And this is equal to $\frac{P(X_2\in\{4,5\},X_3=5\mid X_0=1)}{P(X_2\in\{4,5\}\mid X_0=1)}$, because we have $P(X_0=1)=1$, isn't it? So $P(X_2 \in \{4,5\})=1$, but I'm unable to compute $P(X_3=5,X_2 \in \{4,5\})$. Sorry for my misunderstanding, but how do I compute this exactly?

Comment: ?? $[X_0=1,X_2\in\{4,5\},X_3=5]=[X_0=1,X_1=3,X_2=5,X_3=5]$

Comment: Ok, so this leads to $1 \neq 1/2$ and the counterexample is complete. Thank you very much for your help.